# For loop over text boxes in VB

Tags: vb.net, nullreferenceexception

```
For a = 1 To row
     For b = 1 To clmn
           Form1.Controls("A" & CStr(a) & "T" & CStr(b)).Text = table.Rows(a)(b)
     Next
Next
```

I'm getting an error "System.NullReferenceException"

My text box names are A1T1, A1T2,A1T3,....

How to use for loop over these text boxes?
Eventhough when i start table index from 0,0 the error remains same

Comment: What are the values of `a` and `b` when the exception happens?

Answer (score 0):

The `DataTable` use zero-based indexing. So your first row/column indices are `0`, not `1`.

```
Dim key As String

For a As Integer = 0 To (table.Rows.Count - 1)
    For b As Integer = 0 To (table.Columns.Count - 1)
        key = String.Format("A{0}T{1}", (a + 1), (b + 1))
        If (Me.Controls.ContainsKey(key)) Then
            Me.Controls.Item(key).Text = Convert.ToString(table.Rows(a)(b))
        Else
            Throw New ApplicationException("You need to create a control named: '" & key & "'")
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Don't forget that he still needs the control IDs to be 1-indexed. There won't be a textbox with the ID: `A0T0`

Comment: I want to retrieve data from 1st row and 1st column so i indexed with a=1 and b=1. Eventhough i Started from 0,0 the error remains same. But when i use Form1.A1T1,Text = table.Rows(1)(1) it works fine. @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå

Comment: I'm getting an error that "Additional information: You need to create a control named: 'A2T2'". But A2T2 text box is already present but why is this error coming.... :(( @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå

Comment: Yes, then you need to ask yourself: "Are all my controls parented directly to the form or are they parented to anther control? Controls like a panel or a tabpage?"